# detepicker inside TextBox not working on some aspx pages

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I implemented a datepicker inside my web forms application. 
I tested it on one form, and it was working. The code of the TextBox was:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" class="fieldset__input js__datepicker picker__input" type="text"  id="TbDate" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-readonly="false" />
```

I tried to add the same textbox to another form but it wasn't triggering. 
The other form had the same master page. I copied all the code aspx from the first form to the new one and it was working.
I tried deleting one line at a time to see why the datepicker was working with this code, and found that this line is needed to enable it:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbEmail" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="SingleLine" />
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbEmail" ErrorMessage="The username/email field is required."/>
```

I want the datepicker to open when i click on the **tbDate** TextBox, but it only works if the RequiredFieldValidator for the TextBox **tbEmail** is present. If i delete the validator, the datepicker won't open on the tbDate TextBox. The Validator checks if the input of tbDate is an email format, so there is no connection to the tbDate TextBox.

Also, i tried to delete the other TextBox, and attach the fieldValidator to the tbDate TextBox, and it also works.

I don't understand how this RequiredFieldValidator is helping the datepicker to open, especially inside another textbox?

Understanding this would help me implementing it on other forms.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which datepicker plugin you are using but the markup for the datepickers are not the same.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" class="fieldset__input js__datepicker picker__input" type="text"  id="TbDate" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-readonly="false" />
```

is not the same as

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbEmail" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="SingleLine" />
```

you are missing the classes `fieldset__input js__datepicker picker__input` in the second datepicker which might be selectors for the JS script that's initializing the datepicker. Try adding that and see if it works without the `RequiredFieldValidator`.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. My problem is this:
I want the datepicker to trigger on the tbDate TextBox, but it only works if the RequiredFieldValidator for the TextBox tbEmail is present. If i delete the validator, the datepicker won't trigger on the tbDate TextBox. That is strange since i validate different TextBox. And they are not even in the same div.

Comment: What do you mean by `trigger` ? Is the `datepicker` not initializing in the client side? Or do you mean the `Click` event is not triggered on the code behind?

Comment: I click on the tbDate TextBox, and if the validator for the other TextBox is present, a datepicker calendar will pop up. If i delete the validator for the tbEmail TextBox, when i click tbDate, nothing happens...